# stenciljs all in one bundle with webpack o rollup

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, rollup, stenciljs

I'm trying to generate a bundle for a stenciljs component. With stenciljs with the following stencil.config.js

```
export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'geographicaladdressjs',
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist',
      esmLoaderPath: '../loader',
    },
    {
      type: 'dist-custom-elements',
      externalRuntime: false,
    },
    {
      type: 'docs-readme',
    },

    {
      type: 'www',
      serviceWorker: null, // disable service workers
    },
  ],
  testing: {
    browserHeadless: "new",
    collectCoverage: true,
    clearMocks: true,
    resetMocks: true,
    coverageDirectory: "./reports",
    coverageReporters: ["html", "text", "lcov"],
    reporters:['default', ["jest-html-reporters", {
      "publicPath": "./reports",
      "expand": true,
    }]]
  },
  minifyJs: true,
  minifyCss: true,
  sourceMap: false
};
```

I have 5 files perfectly working
[image]

But I need one js bundle with all project, with webpack I've got one but useless.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './dist/geographicaladdressjs/index.esm.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

How could I have only one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpack solution is this

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';
export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'mycomponent',
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist',
      esmLoaderPath: '../loader',
      empty: true
    },
    {
      type: 'docs-readme',
    },
    {
      type: 'www',
      serviceWorker: null, // disable service workers
    },
  ],
  testing: {
    browserHeadless: "new",
    collectCoverage: true,
    clearMocks: true,
    resetMocks: true,
    coverageDirectory: "./reports",
    coverageReporters: ["html", "text", "lcov"],
    reporters:['default', ["jest-html-reporters", {
      "publicPath": "./reports",
      "expand": true,
    }]]
  },
  minifyJs: true,
  minifyCss: true,
  sourceMap: false
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');
const entryDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/mycomponent/');
const entries = fs.readdirSync(entryDir);
let entryMap = [];
entries.forEach(function(entry){
    let stat = fs.statSync(entryDir + '/' + entry);
    if (stat && !stat.isDirectory()) {
        entryMap.push('./dist/mycomponent/'+ entry);
    }
});


module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry : entryMap,
    output: {
    clean: true,
    filename: 'mycomponent.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/bundle'),
  }
};
```

with mycomponent.js I have all config all in one

Comment: do you have the working copy of this anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

The `dist-custom-elements` target allows you to do your own bundling and distribution. See https://stenciljs.com/docs/custom-elements.

Comment: I read it and I add externalRuntime: false, but generate 5 files instead 1

Comment: You need to do the bundling yourself using webpack, rollup, or some other tool. Stencil does not generate the bundle automatically. See the docs.